# Bad Gateway using Traefik in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik, sticky-session

I am trying to deploy a web application in a docker swarm. I am using Traefik as it allows for session stickiness. As a front-end rule, I have included : "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip: /TestManager"

/TestManager is the name of my service. However, when  I try to navigate to /TestManager, I get a bad gateway.

Here's my Traefik dashboard : [Traefik Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBnLh.png)

I am not sure if I need to edit the front-end rule or the back end rule for the TestManager page to display.

And here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    testmanager:
    image: 10.244.102.10:5000/testmanager
    networks:
      - net
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
      delay: 5s
      max_attempts: 3
      window: 120s
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=autoframework_net"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.backend=testmanager"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip: /TestManager"
      - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.sticky=true"
  ports:
    - "8080"

loadbalancer:
  image: traefik
  command: --docker \
    --docker.swarmmode \
    --docker.watch \
    --web \
    --loglevel=DEBUG
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 9090:8080
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  deploy:
    restart_policy:
      condition: any
    mode: replicated
    replicas: 1
    update_config:
      delay: 2s
    placement:
      constraints: [node.role == manager]
  networks:
    - net
```

networks:
     net:

Comment: Kevin, please refer to this page on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does sound better now @SyakurRahman?